# type is not subtype of type Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I have a user model that am saving in shared preferences when I try to read the data (or even save it ) I get this exception

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'UserPerimeter' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

This is my user model :

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:deepnrise/models/settings/perimeter.dart';
import 'package:deepnrise/models/user/user_perims.dart';

User user(String str) => User.fromJson(json.decode(str));

class User {
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  User({
    required this.identifier,
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.email,
    required this.role,
    required this.perimeters,

  });

  String identifier;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String email;
  String role;
  List<UserPerimeter> perimeters;

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      identifier: json['identifier']?? "",
      firstName: json['firstName']?? "",
      lastName: json['lastName']?? "",
      email: json['email'] ?? "",
      role: json['role'] ?? "",
      perimeters: (json['perimeters'] as List).map((p) => UserPerimeter.fromJson(p)).toList(),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['identifier'] = identifier;
    data['firstName'] = firstName;
    data['lastName'] = lastName;
    data['role'] = role;
    data['email'] = email;
    data['perimeters'] = perimeters;
    return data;
  }
}
```

UserPerim model :

```
import 'dart:convert';

Userperimeters(String str) => UserPerimeter.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String UserPerimToJson(UserPerimeter data) => json.encode(data.tojson());

class UserPerimeter {
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  UserPerimeter(
      {required this.id, required this.label, required this.perimeterId});
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  int id;
  String label;
  int perimeterId;

  factory UserPerimeter.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserPerimeter(
        id: json['id'] ?? "",
        label: json['label'] ?? "",
        perimeterId: json["perimeterId"] ?? "");
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> tojson() => {
        "id": id,
        "label": label,
        "perimeterId": perimeterId,
      };
}
```

When I use the online data it works but in shared prefs doesn't , do anyone know what seems to be the problem , if you can help I'd be grateful .

Comment: you cant save map on shared pref, you can save string,int,bool, so you can save an encoded json of your class (jsonEncode(UserPerimeter)) and when you call the shared pref get metod on the key you decode you value and pass this value on UserPerimeter.fromJson so you can retreive an instance of this class

Comment: can u give me an example please ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert perimeter to a json in the following line:

```
 data['perimeters'] = perimeters;
```

Make it:

```
 data['perimeters'] = perimeters.tojson();
```

Comment: "The method 'tojson' isn't defined for the type 'List'

Comment: The error changed. The issue is that you are adding an object you made in place of a map<string,dynamic> object. convert all your elements inside the list to acceptable json formats and it'll work.

Comment: I am actually converting my elements in the the from string method in the model